# Unexplained network behaviour, Windows 7

Tags: windows, internet

A fresh install of Windows 7 OS. I can access http://cdn.krxd.net/ but I can not access http://cdn.krxd.net/krux.js in all browsers (Firefox, Chrome, IE). Similar behavior with facebook files: http://connect.facebook.net/ and http://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js.

By "can not access" I mean the browser tries for looong time to load it but nothing happens.

I really have not idea what happens.

Answer (score 4):

There is no legitimate domain "facebook.net", facebook.com is the correct domain, and any well-run webhost would prevent direct access to script files as a basic security measure.

You may have had some sort of custom routing on your previous setup that assigned these invalid urls valid destination addresses, which is suspicious at best.

Comment: A simple check of the above data (by you actually accessing those links would've prevented you to write this.)

Comment: I tried resolving facebook.net before writing this, but I did not check the others.

Comment: I mentioned connect.facebook.net rather than just facebook dot net.

Comment: I'm not trying to be mean, however I restate that those links are accessible from another host (on another network) while those with js files are not accessible on the above mentioned host. This kind of behaviour I have never encountered.

Comment: Ok. I see what's going on. Facebook.net is not a valid domain in the US or is not accessible from US-based hosts. When I go to connect.facebook.net I get a message stating "Not a valid locale"